# How to check with C# where a program is installed

Tags: c#

I need to check where a program is installed by program name (name that appears in Add or Remove Programs). What is the best way to that so that it'd work fine for all languages.

Comment: ??? Can you specify your question clearer? Are you asking whether a program is .Net based, or something else?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look into the registry at

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

Just iterate over all subkeys and take a look into the values **DisplayName** and **InstallLocation**. Here you'll find the infos you want and much more ;-)

Comment: At least the InstallLocation can be a work of fiction; for instance, the InstallLocation, according to the registry, for Crystal 11 is "C:\Program Files\Your Company Name\Your Product Name\". In a lot of cases, it is not set, either.

Answer (score 10):

To add to Oliver's answer I have wrapped up this check inside a static method.

```
public static bool IsProgramInstalled(string programDisplayName) {

    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Checking install status of: {0}",  programDisplayName));
    foreach (var item in Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall").GetSubKeyNames()) {

        object programName = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\" + item).GetValue("DisplayName");

        Console.WriteLine(programName);

        if (string.Equals(programName, programDisplayName)) {
            Console.WriteLine("Install status: INSTALLED");
            return true;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Install status: NOT INSTALLED");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at these links

[Using Windows Installer to Inventory Products and Patches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369558%28VS.85%29.aspx)

and

[MsiGetProductInfoEx Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370131%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: MsiGetProductInfo worked well for me in C#. Use pinvoke(http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/msi.msigetproductinfo) to use the function.

Comment: If you want to avoid using PInvoke I think this information can be gotten via Deployment Tools Foundation (DTF), a part of WiX. http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2008/5/16/deployment-tools-foundation-joins-the-wix-toolset