# Iterate through registry entries

Tags: c#

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458483/how-to-check-with-c-where-a-program-is-installed), I need to iterate through entries in

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\
```

to find out the installed path of my application. How to iterate so that I can find out the 
**InstallLocation** value given the **DisplayName**. How to do it efficiently in C#.

Comment: Be aware that to access HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE your application must have administrator privileges (for all OS after XP). I wonder if the question should be 'how to find the installed path of my application'? If the scenario is for upgrades etc. I'm thinking that common application data may be a better go.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Below is code to achieve your goal:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall");
        foreach (var v in key.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(v);

            RegistryKey productKey = key.OpenSubKey(v);
            if (productKey != null)
            {
                foreach (var value in productKey.GetValueNames())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\tValue:" + value);

                    // Check for the publisher to ensure it's our product
                    string keyValue = Convert.ToString(productKey.GetValue("Publisher"));
                    if (!keyValue.Equals("MyPublisherCompanyName", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        continue;

                    string productName = Convert.ToString(productKey.GetValue("DisplayName"));
                    if (!productName.Equals("MyProductName", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        return;

                    string uninstallPath = Convert.ToString(productKey.GetValue("InstallSource"));

                    // Do something with this valuable information
                }
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Edit:** See [this method for a more comprehensive way to find an Applications Install Path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26686738/495455), it demonstrates the `using` disposing as suggested in the comments.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26686738/495455

Comment: You may want to call `Dispose` on the `RegistryKey` instances or, better yet, wrap them in `using` blocks.

Comment: Note: You'll have to cast to an IDisposable first to dispose explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

```
using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Whater\The\Key"))
{
  if (key != null)
  {
    foreach (string ValueOfName in key.GetValueNames())
    {
      try
      {
         bool Value = bool.Parse((string)key.GetValue(ValueOfName));
      }
      catch (Exception ex) {}
    }
 }
}
```

With a bool cast :D - so the string is expected to be True or False.

For the user registry hive use **Registry.CurrentUser** instead of Registry.LocalMachine