# Find the installation path in SharpDevelop

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect, sharpdevelop

I am using **SharpDevelop** , but after I installed my application, especially for Enterprise Architect, I need to know where is the location that the user have chosen through the setup process, because it is important for me to read some data by my Add-in (MyApp) which are already installed in the target path when user install my tool.

I tried to add some RegKeys during installation steps, but I could not hold the path, because basically user can change the path easily ..

```
            <Component Id="setuppath" Guid="FF2212C1-9374-5167-9E1F-3086284BED66" >
                <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="Software\Sparx Systems\DrawUML3D" Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
                    <RegistryValue Type="string" Value="1000" />
                </RegistryKey>
            </Component>
```

Regards,

Comment: There are holo tickboxes next to each answer, marking answers as correct gets you 2 points.  If the answer below doesn't solve your question, dont mark as correct and do more research to find other methods, like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26613336/find-if-3rd-party-software-is-installed-the-install-path-and-the-exes-name

Answer (score 2):

If your add-in is running in EA then you should be able to get the correct directory using something like

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName( 
      System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase );
```

or

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
      System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
```

or a variation thereof

Just make sure you somehow get a hold of the assembly you are interested in and get its location through Reflection.