# Enabling excel add-in programmatically

Tags: c#

Sometimes my excel Addin gets disabled if it ends up being in the disabled COM Addins I can enable it with the following code. However if it ends up in disabled items I can't enable it using this code. Is there a way I can enable a disabled item. Not sure if I could do it using regedit or not.

I get a COM exception `{"Operation aborted (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT))"}`

```
    xl.Application myApp = new xl.Application();

    foreach (COMAddIn currentAddIn in myApp.COMAddIns)
    {
        if (currentAddIn.Description == "Create Excel AddIn" && !currentAddIn.Connect)
        {
            try
            {


                currentAddIn.Connect = true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                CommonMethods.ExceptionHandler("Create tab couldn't be enabled", new StackTrace(true).GetFrame(0).GetFileLineNumber(), new StackTrace(true).GetFrame(0).GetMethod());
            }


            break;
        }

    }


    return false;
}
```

Comment: You can't stop other people disabling you. "What would the world be like if this were possible?" https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040216-00/?p=40603

Comment: @mjwills can I not set something in the regedit to enable it again?

Comment: It's just for testing purposes it's not for other users

Comment: I'm running unit tests and sometimes the addin gets disabled. I have over 200 tests and can't just stop them so I can manually enable the addin

Comment: Run ProcessMonitor really quickly while you manually enable the Add-In to see which registry key/s switch it on or off

Comment: @JeremyThompson in my regedit the path is Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins\Create.ExcelAddIn\LoadBehavior if I change the decimal to 3 it should enable the addin I think

Comment: It is, https://stackoverflow.com/a/14698249/495455

Comment: @JeremyThompson this doesn't show me how to enable it programmatically though

Comment: Oh ok, have this registry class I designed here to do it programmatically: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26613336/495455 sorry that doesn't show how to set load behavior, you can Google that mate "c# set registry key"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was the best and most efficient solution.

```
using (RegistryKey myKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins\Create.ExcelAddIn", true))
{
    if (myKey != null)
    {
        myKey.SetValue("LoadBehavior", "3", RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        myKey.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, glad you got it working and it is good but it isn't the best, because RegistryKey is an unmanaged resource you have to Dispose it, that's why in the link I showed you I use `using`, eg  `using (subkey = key.OpenSubKey(kn))  {`

Answer (score -1):

The only way that I know of for completely disabled add-ins is to delete the registry key in the location below, but it can't be done while Excel is open (change 16.0 to the Office version):

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word\Resiliency\DisabledItems\
```