# Programmatically get list of installed application executables (Windows10, C#)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, known-folders

I want to get a list of applications that are installed and executable on Windows 10 -- i.e. executables of applications a user can launch (UWP and non-UWP). For UWP apps, I want to get its AppUserModelId. For non-UWP apps, I want to get the executable's file location.

So far, I have tried:
1) Going through the registry and iterate through the [installed applications](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26686738/1813311). However, this method goes through all installed applications, the returned list would include things like `microsoft asp.net core 2.1.8 shared framework (x64)`, which I want to eliminate.

2) I found that I can access what I wanted through the special [`Appsfolder`](https://jcutrer.com/windows/find-aumid), by typing `shell:Appsfolder` into either the explorer window or Run. So far I was able to get access to this folder, and iterate through the items and list the names of the files. But I am not sure how to collect information on AppUserModelId (for UWP apps) and filepath (for WPF apps).

Relevant code I used to enumerate Appsfolder files:

```
namespace AppsFolder
{
    ...
    public static class AppsFolder
    {
       ...

       // GUID for shell:Appsfolder
       public static readonly Guid KnownFolderID = new Guid("1e87508d-89c2-42f0-8a7e-645a0f50ca58");

       public static IEnumerable<string> GetItemNames(ESHGDN gdn)
       {
           IShellFolder appsFolder = GetAppsFolder();
           try
           {
               IntPtr enumIDListInterfacePointer;
               appsFolder.EnumObjects(IntPtr.Zero,
                    ESHCONTF.SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS | ESHCONTF.SHCONTF_FOLDERS,
                   out enumIDListInterfacePointer);
               using (var enumIDList = new
                      EnumIDListWrapper(enumIDListInterfacePointer))
               {
                  var names = new List<string>();
                  foreach (var pidl in enumIDList)
                  {
                      STRRET name;
                      recycleBin.GetDisplayNameOf(
                              pidl.DangerousGetHandle(),
                             gdn,
                             out name);
                      names.Add(STRRETToString(ref name, pidl));
                      if (name.uType != (int)STRRETType.Offset)
                         Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(name.data.pOleStr);
                  }
                  return names;
               }
           }
           finally
           {
               Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(recycleBin);
           }
        }

        private static IShellFolder GetAppsFolder()
        {
            IShellFolder desktop;
            NativeMethod.SHGetDesktopFolder(out desktop);
            try
            {
                Guid shellFolderInterfaceId = typeof(IShellFolder).GUID;
                IntPtr recycleBinShellFolderInterfacePointer;
                desktop.BindToObject(
                    GetItemIDList().DangerousGetHandle(),
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    ref shellFolderInterfaceId,
                    out recycleBinShellFolderInterfacePointer);
                return (IShellFolder)Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(
                             recycleBinShellFolderInterfacePointer);
            }
            finally
            {
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(desktop);
            }
         }

         public static SafeCoTaskMemHandleZeroIsInvalid GetItemIDList()
         {
             SafeCoTaskMemHandleZeroIsInvalid pidl;
             Guid guid = KnownFolderID;
             NativeMethod.SHGetKnownFolderIDList(
                ref guid, 0, IntPtr.Zero, out pidl);
             return pidl;
         }
     }
}
```

Executed as:

```
string[] names = AppsFolder.GetItemNames(AppsFolder.ESHGDN.SHGDN_INFOLDER).ToArray();
for (int i=0; i<names.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(names[i]);
}
```

The [`ILaunchSourceAppUserModelID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ilaunchsourceappusermodelid) interface provides a method to get the AppUserModelID, but I'm not sure how to get access to this interface through my IShellFolder interface. Also, how do I get the actual file location within the AppsFolder virtual folder to actual exe's filepath?

Comment: What you describe only works for apps that are registered with the OS, but that is not a requirement. Apps can be installed and be executable without being registered with the OS. If you really want to find *everything*, you will likely end up having to enumerate the whole file system.

Comment: Right, I understand that. At this point I just want to find those that are registered with the OS. Can you recommend a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution, you don't need to add any extra dll or namespace to get the app names from window app store:

```
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"Get-AppxPackage | select name";
            p.Start();
            output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            p.WaitForExit();
```

all applications list included in the output.

Answer (score 7):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57195200/1969903) answer.

In short, add the [Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack-Shell](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack-Shell/) nuget package to your project and then use this code:

```
// GUID taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/knownfolderid
var FODLERID_AppsFolder = new Guid("{1e87508d-89c2-42f0-8a7e-645a0f50ca58}");
ShellObject appsFolder = (ShellObject)KnownFolderHelper.FromKnownFolderId(FODLERID_AppsFolder);

foreach (var app in (IKnownFolder)appsFolder)
{
    // The friendly app name
    string name = app.Name;
    // The ParsingName property is the AppUserModelID
    string appUserModelID = app.ParsingName; // or app.Properties.System.AppUserModel.ID
    // You can even get the Jumbo icon in one shot
    ImageSource icon =  app.Thumbnail.ExtraLargeBitmapSource;
}
```

To start the app:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", @" shell:appsFolder\" + appUserModelID);
```

Works for both regular apps and store apps.

Comment: The provided package is not maintained anymore. Here is the new one with support for .NET 6: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft-WindowsAPICodePack-Shell/

Comment: Also, launching the app with the Process.Start() method doesn't work when there is a GUID in a AppUserModelID (ex. {F38BF404-1D43-42F2-9305-67DE0B28FC23}\regedit.exe). It just starts the default Documents folder 

Comment: @DamianUbowski
I'm working on my own code to read the contents of the virtual folder so that I can get rid of WindowsAPICodePack-Shell completely.
As for the other topic, you should be starting it like this `Process.Start("explorer.exe", @"shell:appsFolder\{F38BF404-1D43-42F2-9305-67DE0B28FC23}\regedit.exe");`
Tested just now and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Application User Model ID (AUMID) for all apps installed for the current user by running the following command in Windows PowerShell command prompt:

```
get-StartApps
```

To get AUMIDs for Windows Store apps installed for another user, run the following command in Windows PowerShell command prompt:

```
$installedapps = get-AppxPackage

$aumidList = @()
foreach ($app in $installedapps)
{
    foreach ($id in (Get-AppxPackageManifest $app).package.applications.application.id)
    {
        $aumidList += $app.packagefamilyname + "!" + $id
    }
}

$aumidList
```

More detailed information you can refer to "[Find the Application User Model ID of an installed app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/find-the-application-user-model-id-of-an-installed-app)".

What you need to do is call related registry API or Powershell command from C#.

Comment: Looks like one way to do it, I will try it. Is it not possible with winapi?

Comment: This doesn't list Chrome / Edge web pages installed as apps.

Answer (score 0):

You get the AppUserModelId with **IShellFolder2.GetDetailsEx** and **PKEY_AppUserModel_ID**

(tested in C# on Windows 10)

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
public struct PROPERTYKEY
{
    private readonly Guid _fmtid;
    private readonly uint _pid;

    public PROPERTYKEY(Guid fmtid, uint pid)
    {
        _fmtid = fmtid;
        _pid = pid;
    }

    public static readonly PROPERTYKEY PKEY_AppUserModel_ID = new PROPERTYKEY(new Guid("9F4C2855-9F79-4B39-A8D0-E1D42DE1D5F3"), 5);     
}
```