# How to determine install scope of existing app?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have an installer based on the `WixUI_Advanced` that allows users to choose their install scope (per user or machine wide).

When upgrading (have an existing app with a lower version installed) I would like to hide the install scope screen and automatically select the install scope they chose last time.

How can I tell what install scope was used for the previous installation?

---

**Edit**

Looking at my MSI logs I can see that my existing installation is found:

```
// Existing user specific installation
FindRelatedProducts: Found application: {C5D3DCD0-4A97-4224-AF22-BDDEB357EEB7}
MSI (c) (C4:F0) [11:11:39:289]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED property. Its value is '{C5D3DCD0-4A97-4224-AF22-BDDEB357EEB7}'.
MSI (c) (C4:F0) [11:11:39:289]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MIGRATE property. Its value is '{C5D3DCD0-4A97-4224-AF22-BDDEB357EEB7}'.

// Existing machine wide installation
MSI (c) (2C:4C) [11:03:19:258]: FindRelatedProducts: current install is per-user.  Related install for product '{C5D3DCD0-4A97-4224-AF22-BDDEB357EEB7}' is per-machine.  Skipping...
```

I can see the `WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED` and `MIGRATE` properties are set only when the existing installation's scope matches the current installation which makes sense.  Perhaps I can use `FindRelatedProducts` directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up checking for an entry with the `DisplayName` matching our app name in the registry in (inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13659661/1438809)):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

Then I grabbed the content of `InstallLocation` to determine the install scope:

```
if (installLocation == string.Empty)
{
    // Installed before we introduced scope => never set install location
    return ExistingInstallation.MachineWide;
}
else if (installLocation.Contains(_programFilesPath))
{
    return ExistingInstallation.MachineWide;
}
else
{
    return ExistingInstallation.UserSpecific;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> This is not a complete answer. I had to add as an answer because of
>   formatting requirements.

---

**UPDATE**: Looked at this, ran out of time again. ***`This really is no answer at all, but just lobbing it to you in case it can help you research it yourself`***.

***Registry Persistence***: I assume you have tried to persist **`ALLUSERS`** and / or the installation scope in the registry and read it back in the updated MSI? I didn't look at that. For that to work you have to do it in the first release of the package and keep it up later.

***MSI API Automation***: Here is a little hack to find the previously installed products on the box (this essentially runs similar stuff as `"FindRelatedProducts"` inside MSI files):

***Inside MSI***:

```vb
Set upgrades = Session.installer.RelatedProducts("INSERT-UPGRADE-CODE")
For Each u In upgrades
    scope = Session.installer.ProductInfo(u,"AssignmentType")
    MsgBox CStr(scope)
Next
```

***Standalone, run script directly*** (install the MSI with the upgrade code specified first):

```vb
Set installer = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
Set upgrades = installer.RelatedProducts("INSERT-UPGRADE-CODE")

For Each u In upgrades
   MsgBox "Product Code: " & u & vbNewLine & "Installation Context: " & installer.ProductInfo(u,"AssignmentType")   
Next

MsgBox "Done"
```

I was thinking to do something like this in the GUI-sequence, but ran out of time again:

```vb
If scope = 1 Then
  Session.Property("ALLUSERS") = "1"
  Session.Property("MSIINSTALLPERUSER") = ""
  Session.Property("WixAppFolder") = "WixPerMachineFolder"
Else
  Session.Property("ALLUSERS") = "2"
  Session.Property("MSIINSTALLPERUSER") = "1"
  Session.Property("WixAppFolder") = "WixPerUserFolder"
End If
```

***WiX Snippets***:

```
<Binary Id='Scope.vbs' SourceFile='Debugging Custom Actions\Scope.vbs' />
<CustomAction Id='Scope.vbs' VBScriptCall='' BinaryKey='Scope.vbs' Execute='immediate' Return='ignore'/>

<..>

<InstallUISequence>
  <Custom Action='Scope.vbs' Before='CostInitialize' />      
</InstallUISequence>
```

---

I was going to look at this, but ran out of time. Essentially **`WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED`** will be set in the new setup being installed. [**See this answer for more**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51090120/129130). You could use that property to determine whether to hide or show a button. I tested that briefly and it worked, but implementing it in WiX is harder. You need to override the whole dialog I think.

In MSI tables, it would be something like this (Orca screenshot - [MSI viewer tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48482546/129130)):

[image: Orca]

---

- [**Here is an answer on MSI and Burn GUI issues**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52654935/changing-text-color-to-wix-dialogs/52674815#52674815) (please check section 2: `Change Default Dialogs - Advanced Dialogs`).

Throwing in some more links:

- [Removing Default dialogs from MSI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52446750/removing-default-dialogs-from-msi/52451051#52451051)
- [Wix, custom dialog when previous version exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33690724/wix-custom-dialog-when-previous-version-exists/52765526#52765526)
- [Back/Next Button in UI using Wix toolset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56757662/back-next-button-in-ui-using-wix-toolset/56761784#56761784)
- http://neilsleightholm.blogspot.com/2008/08/customised-uis-for-wix.html

Comment: Overriding the whole dialog isn't an issue, I'm doing that already :P  The problem is `WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED` only gets set if the current install scope matches the install scope of the existing install.  Hence I'm trying to figure out the install scope of the existing install.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't look properly at this. Added a hacky little VBScript to try to get previous installation scope. Have a look, try the standalone one first maybe? You might need the Win32 / C++ functions to get proper granularity and control. I am not sure. It is very complicated to make a proper dual-scope MSI package. As people discover when they try.

Comment: No worries :)  I was hoping to have some magic variables set by MSI/Wix, but it looks like I may have to resort to writing some code :P  Ooh, just read your registry suggestion.  That could work too.  Let me mess around a bit.

Comment: Yes, I guess I don't need to remind you that this is very high WTF factor - if you pardon my French (or *"resident evil of all things"*). This technology bites back. Be sure to test in many installation modes: `install`, `repair`, `modify`, `self-repair`, `patching`, `upgrades`, etc... There are many cog-wheels in an MSI and they interact so unexpectedly. Hard core testing needed.

Comment: Ah, almost forgot. Let me send you to [Rob Mensching's Remember Pattern](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/the-wix-toolsets-remember-property-pattern/). Maybe you have already seen it. Very important read if you go the registry way.

Comment: I'm trying to get a C# custom action working, but it looks like my `Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.Installer` from `WiX Toolset v3.11\SDK\Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll` doesn't have a `RelatedProducts` property or method :/